# Как объединить множество объектов JSON в один массив?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular

Есть множество JSON объектов, вывод в консоли такой, каждая строка новый объект, как мне объединить все эти объекты в один один массив?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в чем проблема запушить их все в один массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [];
arr.push(json1);
arr.push(json2);
...
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]